# Printing does not work from my Raspberry Pi 4 and Cups 2.2.10

Tags: raspberry-pi, printing, cups, hp-printer

Anyone knows what could be the problem with Cups setup with my RPi 4 and laser printer? What could I do next? I want to be able to print from my laser printer from my phones, multiple computers and I don't want to bring my laptop to the printer. I want to print it via Wi-Fi, using my RPi4.

These are components I'm using:

- Cups 2.2.10
- HP LaserJet Professional P1102
- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, 2GB

WHAT I DID:

- I have installed Cups onto my RPi4 following these instructions: 
  https://www.howtogeek.com/169679/how-to-add-a-printer-to-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-computer/
- I've "Add Printer" on the CUPS 2.2.10 Administration panel
- suitable drivers were not found, so I have installed `sudo apt-get install printer-driiver-splix` and then also `sudo apt install hplip` and then "HP LaserJet Professional P1102" drivers appeared
- I have rebooted RPi multiple times between these steps
- I tried both Local Printers appeared in the list. 1st: `HP LaserJet Professional P1102 USB 000000000Q86SW5NSI1c HPLIP (HP LaserJet Professional P1102)`
- Also tried another option `HP LaserJet Professional P1102 (HP LaserJet Professional P1102)`
- both times I was able to select `HP LaserJet Professional p1102, hpcups 3.18.12, requires proprietary plugin (en)` driver. Using Developer Inspection tool, I was able to see the PPD file name which is being selected: `hplip:0/ppd/hplip/HP/hp-laserjet_professional_p1102.ppd` (worth mentioning, that there were multiple options like that in the list)
- then I used VNC to connect to the RPi 4 and tried printing from the RPi locally and then the following failure happened:
  [image: Print Error on RPi 4]
  [image: failed print on CUPS 2.2.10]

When diagnosing with Printing troubleshooter, this is the error listed below:

> "Printer 'HP_LaserJet_Professional_P1102':
>
> 'hplip.plugin'

See screenshot below
[image: Printing troubleshooter]

Then going further with troubleshooting, I have used following command to Retrieve Journal Entries:

> su -c 'journalctl -u cups.service --since="None" --until="2020-04-15 21:21:46"' > troubleshoot-logs.txt

And then all logs I've retrieved multiple times are seen here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Jj_g-S5_586j1KfRBs-dorZ4eqTozAGm

It seems like it's a deadlock now. Anyone has any suggestion how to move forward?  I want to be able to print from my laser printer from my phones, multiple computers and I don't want to bring my laptop to the printer. I want to print it via Wi-Fi, using my RPi4.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem today. To fix it I ran:

```
sudo hp-plugin
```

One must be connected to the Internet to do this. Now I am able to print.

resource is [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html).